# Python date time conversion

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, string-conversion

I have a string which would be like

```
"Wednesday, December 13, 2017 6:48:04 AM"
```

which I need to convert it into "8/9/2017 10:44" format.
I have tried using strptime, like so:

```
strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

but it did not work.

Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format doesn't match your input.  Try this instead:

```
time.strptime(
    "Wednesday, December 13, 2017 6:48:04 AM",
    '%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Returns the proper

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=13,
                 tm_hour=6, tm_min=48, tm_sec=4,
                 tm_wday=2, tm_yday=347, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation on [strftime and strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) you're missing a couple pieces in your format string. 
Use this as the strptime format:

```
'%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p'
```

and this as your strftime format:

```
'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'
```

you can combine the two methods in one line as follows to give you your desired result:

```
time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', time.strptime("Wednesday, December 13, 2017 6:48:04 AM", '%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine it with strftime to get the format you want

`time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", (time.strptime('Jun 1 2005 1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')))`

'Wed, 01 Jun 2005 13:33:00 +0000'